# Turning simple polygons about a point in Python Turtle

Tags: python, polygon, turtle-graphics, shapes

I need help turning polygon shapes (triangle and square) in Python turtle to match a picture.

Below I am trying to copy the image. [image: Image looking to copy]
I specifically need help on what to add to my code given the triangle and square to have them repeat outwards like the picture. Because as of now the triangles and squares look like this (pentagon code is correct and works) All help is appreciated. Thank you. [image: Triangles and Squares now]

```
import turtle 

def polygon(turtle, side, length):
    turtle.color("Blue")
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.backward(length)
        turtle.left(side)
def polygon1(turtle, side1, length):
    turtle.color("Green")
    for i in range(3):
        turtle.left(side1)
        turtle.forward(length)
def polygon2(turtle, side2, length):
    turtle.color("Red")
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(side2)

def main():
    my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    Bill = turtle.Turtle()
    length = 100
    side = 90
    side1 = 120
    side2 = 72
    Bill.pensize(5)
    Bill.speed(0)

    #Pentagons
    Bill.pu()
    Bill.right(180)
    y = -45
    for i in range(5):
        Bill.pu()
        Bill.goto(60, y)
        Bill.pd()
        polygon2(Bill, side2, length)
        y -= 20

    #Triangle
    Bill.pu()
    Bill.left(240)
    x = 45
    for j in range(5):
        Bill.pu()
        Bill.goto(10, x)
        Bill.pd()
        polygon1(Bill, side1, length)
        x += 20

    #Square
    Bill.pu()
    Bill.left(240)
    b = 6
    for b in range(5):
        Bill.pu()
        Bill.goto(148, b)
        Bill.pd()
        polygon(Bill, side, length)
        b -= 20



    wn.exitonclick()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pentagon code is correct and works

I don't believe the pentagon code is correct nor that you're approaching this in the correct way.  The inner three shapes should form an equilateral triangle -- yours don't as you're eyeballing instead of calculating.  Instead of trying to get the turtle to be in the right spot, why not have the turtle move forward in the direction of the sides of this central triangle, drawing polygons as it goes.

That is, embrace the drawing as a whole rather than trying to divide and conquer.

We'd need to make sure the polygon drawing code restores the turtle's state when it's done, so it can simply move forward to the next polygon.  We'll need to make explicit which numbers are arbitrary, and which are calculable.  Although the original diagram appears to use at least three turtles to achieve it's result, we'll do it with one as you attempted:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

SHAPES = [(5, "Red"), (3, "Green"), (4, "Blue")]

LENGTH = 100
DELTA = 20
REPLICATIONS = 5
THICKNESS = 5

HEIGHT = (3 ** 0.5 / 2) * LENGTH  # assumes 3 shapes, should fix!
DIVISIONS = 360 / len(SHAPES)

def polygon(turtle, sides, color):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(LENGTH / 2)

    for _ in range(sides):
        turtle.right(360 / sides)
        turtle.forward(LENGTH)

    turtle.backward(LENGTH / 2)  # restore turtle to original state
    turtle.right(90)

wn = Screen()

bill = Turtle()
bill.speed('fastest')
bill.pensize(THICKNESS)

bill.penup()

for offset, (sides, color) in enumerate(SHAPES):

    bill.setheading(-DIVISIONS * offset - 90)
    bill.forward(HEIGHT / 3)  # assumes 3 shapes, should fix!

    for _ in range(REPLICATIONS):
        bill.pendown()
        polygon(bill, sides, color)
        bill.penup()
        bill.forward(DELTA)

    bill.home()

wn.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I like this approach better. More succinct and complete.